# How to print expect send statements in bash script and compare them

Tags: bash, expect

I am using a bash script to clone all my repositories in git. I have all repositories in a file. It reads repositories one by one call my expect script which spawns git clone. I am using expect because it asks me for a password every time I clone, So that expect can provide it the password. 
It works without any issues when my password is correct. But if my password is wrong I want to go to my bash script and do something and terminate the bash script.

Bash script calls expect script like this

```
expect ~/expect_script.exp
```

My expect script

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
puts "## Starting the expect script... ##" 
spawn git clone ssh://$GIT_CENTRAL_PATH/web/$sub_dir_type/$repository
expect "*?assword: "
send $PASS\r
expect {

    -re “remote: Counting objects:*?” {send “echo running\r”}
    -re “Permission denied*?” {send “password denied”}
}
```

I want if the password is correct git starts Counting objects and cloning the repository. If the password is wrong, I want the bash script to do something and stop. Could you please help me with this problem. If you are not able to understand what I want to achieve please let me know.

Comment: I have never used `expect`, but i guess it would return an exit status of `1`. If yes, in the beginning of your `bash` script, place `set -e`.

Comment: Also it is probably asking for your password because you are cloning it into some directory that needs root permission. If not necessary why not clone in one of user directories?

Answer (score 0):

I would use "success/failure" exit statuses to signal expect's result.

```
expect {
    "Permission denied*?” {exit 1}
    "remote: Counting objects:*?"
}
set timeout -1
expect eof
exit 0
```

Then the shell script looks like:

```
if expect ~/expect_script.ext; then
    echo "repo cloned"
else
    echo "password denied"
fi
```

A couple of notes:

1. Your expect patterns are glob patterns, not regular expressions
2. You have "curly" quotes in your expect script. Take care with your editor to use plain quotes.

Comment: I changed my script I enter the wrong password it says Permission denied and ask me to enter the password again and nothing happens. I changed instead of Permission denied, changed the expect to password with send as exit 1 but nothing happens.